# Does dependency injection make sense for "pass by value" types? Is there a difference in DI for Value Types and Reference Types

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, solid-principles, clean-architecture

There are two type of data structures.

**Pass by reference** and
**Pass by value**

So I was studying Dependency Injection in depth.
I had a doubt which is **"Does dependency injection makes sense for value types"**?

I mean should I take care of something when I am passing **Value Types** as Dependencies?

And is there any difference when your dependency is a **Value Type** or a **Reference Type**? *or am I just over thinking*

Comment: Note that data structures and parameter passing are unrelated, orthogonal concepts. Reference type != pass-by-reference and value type != pass-by-value. For example, Java has both reference types and value (primitive) types; however, _both_ types are passed by value, never by reference: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1371329)